# html text encoding

Tags: html, encode

Ive got a text area which clients can enter notes (on their clients).
But if the clients enters text that contains ' then it breaks.

I had the same problem with new linesa \r \n but fixed it with this

```
notes:'@Html.Raw(client.Notes.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"&#13;&#10"))'});
```

How do I fix the ' problem?
Example please

thanks

Comment: `it breaks`, you say. How? What symptoms? Errors? Exceptions? End of the world?

Comment: the record is returned but im using jquery template to map the object, jquery then does not like it so the ui shows no notes.

Comment: "jquery then does not like it" - can you be more specific? Are you getting any errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: So it breaks the code, and returns notes: 'll'l&#13;&#10Pay Later' this is terminating the statement early to many '

Comment: This fixes it Notes: '@Html.Raw(client.Notes.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"&#13;&#10").Replace("'","&#39;"))' a bit rubbish tho, any thing to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is when you interpreting the text back into the Dom with JQuery then you could html encode all your string with a function like this

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```